# SqlException cause all subsequent db call to fail with same exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an application on ASP.NET Core 2.2 and using Entity Framework Core 2.2.6.

I just encountered one problem. I am updating entities in the cycle, like this

```
   foreach (EntityDTO entityDTO in entityList)
   {
       try
       {
            DBOperationOne(entityDTO)
            DBOperationTwo(entityDTO)
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
       }
   }
```

And for one entity I get this SQL exception

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.

This is ok, I know why this happened, but the problem is next: after this error, all subsequent db calls for another entity result in the same exception! Even if it tries to update other fields with absolutely correct data! and if you try to run generated SQL for subsequent call outside of Entity Framework it will be completed successfully! But inside this loop all subsequent calls fails

My questions is: why this is happening and how I can avoid this behavior?

and here DBOperation methods example:

```
pulic Entity DBOperationOne(entityDTO)
{
    Entity entity = _mapper.Map<Entity>(entityDTO);
    _context.Entity.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
     return entity;
}

pulic Entity2 DBOperationTwo(entityDTO)
{
    Entity2 entity = _mapper.Map<Entity2>(entityDTO);
    _context.Entity2.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
     return entity;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

I've tried to place everything in the `TransactionScope` with `RequiresNew` transaction, but this do not help

Comment: Why are you trying to save data that doesn't fit anyways? Add validation to your app to make sure you don't try to save bad data.

Comment: One of the many reasons to not store and reuse EF context. Create new one for each logical operation.

Comment: @Evk hey, how can i do it if it injected via depencencyInjection? could you throw me some keywords, I understand this might be very basic, but my head is spinning, thanks in advance

Comment: @user2489102 The factory pattern would allow you to inject a factory that creates DB contexts on demand.

Comment: In web server it's usually a common practice indeed to inject one context per request. However, it's not a common practice to try to recover from errors (usually, error goes right to a client and then client might retry). So in your case you can inject context factory instead, and then resolve new instance from that factory every time you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your entity model still has the changes that you made that are causing the sql exception when you try to apply them to the database. So when you try to update the database with your next changes, it is trying to make the problematic update as well.

You can avoid it by adding validation to prevent your entity model being changed in a way that will break when you try to apply the changes to the database.

Comment: Hey. Do you mean manual validation? or there is an already solution that exists in Asp.Net?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/validation

Answer (score 0):

Well your line `_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;`
happens after the error is thrown in .SaveChanges

So that will never happen (and hence the context still thinks it needs to be added the next time)

If you move the line `_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;` to a finally block of a try/finally then it'll be ok, as it will still happen in the event of an error in the SaveChanges().

EG

```
public Entity DBOperationOne(entityDTO)
{
    Entity entity = _mapper.Map<Entity>(entityDTO);
    try
    { 
        _context.Entity.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    finally
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
    return entity;
}
```